# Decimal complex number in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, decimal, complex-numbers

I want to multiply complex number and decimal number, but the error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'decimal.Decimal' and 'complex'` pops up. Is there a way to do this? It is important to use decimal(not float) type because I need high accuracy

If i try to convert complex number into decimal, it throws the error `TypeError: conversion from complex to Decimal is not supported`

Code example:

```
from decimal import Decimal

a = Decimal(3.4) * complex(3, 4)
```

Comment: is there a reason why you have to use `Decimal()`?

Comment: @DrBwts I'm wondering this too. You can just convert to float and do it `a = float(Decimal(3.4)) * (3 + 4j)`